# appending index of an item to another list in python

Tags: python, list, append

I used the code below to append the index of an item to another list, but it only gives the index of some previous occurrence of the same item.

```
for x,y in zip(answer,std_answer):
        if x != y:
           wrong_ans.append(answer.index(x))
```

Please i need the code to append the exact index of the item to another list. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(answer, std_answer)):
   if x != y
       wrong_ans.append(i)
```

`enumerate` is a built-in function that iterates over an iterable, returning the items of the iterable and the iteration index. It's both faster than `index(x)`, which searches your list each time it runs, and not subject to identifying earlier appearances of the value.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
for i in range(min(len(std_answer), len(answer))):
    if answer[i] != std_answer[i]:
        wrong_ans.append(i)
```